# Release memory in a code using matplotlib?

Tags: python, memory-management, matplotlib

Well, I tried many things and I'm almost convinced that there is no way to solve my problem.
Here I go...
I'm writing a simple software with tkinter and in one part of this software I use matplotlib and basemaps to provide some maps to the user. 
The problem is that in those maps are loaded a relative big amount of data and in some computers it can be a problem if the user open many maps.
One part of mu code (the critical) is:

```
def plota_bacia():  
    global status_shape,pontos,arq
    print status_shape 
    if status_shape == True:
    fig = pyl.figure(figsize=(12,8))
        fig.canvas.set_window_title('Bacia fornecida pelo arquivo: '+arq)
        fig.patch.set_facecolor('white')
        m = Basemap(projection='merc',llcrnrlat=-32.5,urcrnrlat=5.0,llcrnrlon=-65.0,urcrnrlon=-33.0,lat_ts=20,resolution='c')
        parallels = arange(-50.,20,0.5)
        meridians = arange(-90.,0.,0.5)
        ptos = []
        for x,y in zip(pontos[0],pontos[1]): 
            x1,y1=m(x,y)
            ptos.append((x1,y1))
        p = Polygon(ptos,facecolor='red',edgecolor='green',linewidth=1) 
        pyl.gca().add_patch(p) 

        pyl.title(arq)
        xmin,ymin = m(min(pontos[0])-0.5,min(pontos[1])-0.5)
        xmax,ymax = m(max(pontos[0])+0.5,max(pontos[1])+0.5)
        m.drawparallels(parallels,labels=[1,0,0,0],fontsize=16)
        m.drawmeridians(meridians,labels=[0,0,0,1],fontsize=16)       
        m.readshapefile(dir_shape+'Brasil/BRASIL','r')
        pyl.xlim([xmin,xmax])
        pyl.ylim([ymin,ymax])
        pyl.show()
    else:tkMessageBox.showinfo( "Gráfico da bacia","Entre com uma bacia",parent=top)
```

Doing some tests I understood that the problem is way how python manages the memory, for example:

```
from pylab import *
f = range(1,10000000,1)
plot(f)
show()
del f ; gc.collect()
```

If I put the line "del f ; gc.collect()" after the second one ("f = range(1,10000000,1)") I have some space released related to delete the variable "f", but once I plot "f", I supose a matplotlib object is conected to the part of the memory related to "f" and for this reason I can't release that part of the memory. 
Is that correct? I tried cla(), clf(), close() and this not help me.
Sorry if I did some stupid, I program many things in python, but I'm a environmental engineer, not a programmer.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: don't use the `pyplot` interface if you are embedding.  There are lots of messy internal references to the artists. In your two example, all the data in `f` must be copied into the data structures of the figure.

Comment: How are you monitoring memory usage?

Comment: esmit, I was monitoring with a simple monitoring tool in Ubuntu.
tcaswell, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After `pyl.show()` add `pyl.close(fig.number); del fig`.

Comment: fyi, `pyl.close(fig)` is sufficient